# Build failing in intellij

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, intellij-idea

Current scenario : Two file in same package but in different module one in main and other in Test.

Reason : Because when I run my unit test it automatically access file in test module,where as when I run the main module it access the file in main module.

Problem : Now when I am running build task it is failing. As now my unit test are failing as they are not able to pick the right file of the two.Due to which my build is failing.

Is there anyway I can overcome this issue.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Like giving that minimal example.

Comment: But guessing: simple don't use the same name twice in an incompatible way. Maybe you should define an interface and allow for different implementations.

Comment: Reason for using same name is that we can mock it by just putting implementation in that file in test module.

Comment: That sounds like the wrong approach. You shouldn't mock a class, instead work with interfaces. The trouble you are having is rooted in a bad design. Instead of wasting your time fighting tooling, you better fix your broken design. Learn how to properly mock dependencies instead of inventing a solution that ain't no solution.

Comment: You are correct will do that